# How to calculate percentiles by time windows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a dataset like below. Where I have some values against time in milliseconds.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (TimeInMillis BIGINT, value BigInt);
INSERT INTO @Table (TimeInMillis, value) VALUES
(1680195900000, 8 ), (1680195923000, 5 ), (1680195924000, 7 ),
(1680195927000, 12), (1680195962000, 8 ), (1680195963000, 9 ),
(1680195964000, 15), (1680196025000, 9 ), (1680196028000, 8 ),
(1680196029000, 15);
```

Now my requirement is to summarize the data to minute granularity, so I should select each Minute in a given time window and group the rows within the each minute and then calculate the percentiles(e.g: 90th and 99th  percentile) of the dataset within each minute. The above dataset should give the following output once the calculation is done. As you can see first 4 rows of the dataset belong to the minute 1680195900000 so we will calculate the percentiles for those 4 rows which results 10.8 and 11.88.

| TimeInMillis(BigInt) | Percentile90 | Percentile99 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1680195900000 | 10.8 | 11.88 |
| 1680195960000 | 13.8 | 14.88 |
| 1680196020000 | 13.8 | 14.88 |

Eventually I will be calculating the percentiles for hourly windows as well. I have some code that already does this, but I thought it would be better if I can offload this to the DB itself. Appreciate any help here.

I have checked multiple SO questions and nothing is capturing this particular requirement.

---

Potential answer based on Patrick Hurst's answer.

```sql
SELECT a.MinsInMillis, a.p90, a.p99, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
  FROM (
        SELECT (TimeInMillis - (TimeInMillis % 60000)) AS MinsInMillis, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.90) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Value) OVER (PARTITION BY (TimeInMillis - (TimeInMillis % 60000))) AS p90,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Value) OVER (PARTITION BY (TimeInMillis - (TimeInMillis % 60000))) AS p99
          FROM Test
       ) a

GROUP BY a.MinsInMillis, a.p90, a.p99
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.MinsInMillis, a.p90, a.p99, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
  FROM (
        SELECT TimeInMillis/60000 AS MinsInMillis, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Value) OVER (PARTITION BY TimeInMillis/60000) AS p90, 
               PERCENTILE_CONT(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Value) OVER (PARTITION BY TimeInMillis/60000) AS p99
          FROM @Table
       ) a
 GROUP BY a.MinsInMillis, a.p90, a.p99
```

You can use the `ROUND` function with a negative length to round up numbers.
Using that, we can use the `PERCENTILE_CONT` windowed analytic function to determine the percentiles.

Comment: You beat me to it. :D But i think he wanted in minutes, so you should probably do / 60000 instead of rounding

Comment: Thank you verymuch for taking time to answer. But rounding or dividing by 60000 will not get you do the closest minute I believe? So the logic I have in my program is something like this, TimeInMillis is presorted, So I will get the first row then do `TimeInMillis - (TimeInMillis%60000` which will give `1680195900000` the starting minute. Then I would calculate each partition by adding 60K to the currentTime (1680195900000 + 60000 = 1680195960000) etc. Hope it is clear.

Comment: I tried to adopt the same logic I use and came up with a potential answer. I added that to the Original question. Does it look right to you guys?

Comment: Also I have more more question, Is there any way to optimize this query? For example can we calculate multiple percentiles within the same Windows rather than Windowing the records per percentile. In the real use case I'm calculating 10 percentiles with 1M+ records, hence want to make sure the query is fully optimized.